# Quick way to add a key to every value in a list

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of elements

`tagsList = ['dun', 'dai', 'che']`

How do I convert the above into the following?

```
tagsDictionaries = [
  {
    'name': 'dun'
  },
  {
    'name': 'dai'
  },
  {
    'name': 'che'
  }
]
```

I want to do this with a `for` loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tagsDictionaries = [{'name': item} for item in tagsList]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work for a flat dictionary. It needs unique key values each time:

```
for tag in tagsList:
    tagDictionary.update({tag + 'uniquekey': tag})
```

What you show in your example would be a list of dictionaries which can be accomplished as follows:

```
for tag in tagsList:
    tagListDict.append({'name': tag})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic for loop that will get you the output that you are seeking:

```
tagsList = ['dun', 'dai', 'che']
tagsDictionaries = []   


for name in tagsList:
   new_dict = {'name': name}
   tagsDictionaries.append(new_dict)
print(tagsDictionaries)
```

Here is your output:

```
[{'name': 'dun'}, {'name': 'dai'}, {'name': 'che'}]
```